# DNS and Subnet mask

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

If I change the subnet mask on my network will it effect the DNS server there? I just did an upgrade from 03 to 08 AD and when i did the upgrade i by accident put the subnet mask at 255.255.255.128, ive then changed the pc's to the same. It was 255.255.255.0 and our router also has 255.255.255.0. Seems like since I did this the DNS has been "flaking out"

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Changing the subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.255.128 will halve your subnet range of IPs.

You need just to make sure that all needed services including the default gateway resides in the same subnet. Otherwise, you may end up having some PCs/servers in two separate subnets.

Comment: Ah...and the light bulb goes off! Ok I understand now. I'm a SQL/C# developer by nature not a network admin so I had to ask as Im the only IT guy for the company here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cut the IP space in half by changing the subnet mask. If you have IPs in the .1 to .127 range, they will not be able to communicate with any IPs in the .128 to .255 range. This has little to do with DNS.